# Anime with two school girls running down a hallway from a bunch of guys or zombies

Tags: story-identification, anime

Anime with two school girls saying they're best friends while running down a hallway from a bunch of guys (or zombies). One girl falls and the other just pushes her friend to the group of guys. I remember seeing it in a clip on TikTok.

Comment: This question is very terse. You could improve it by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: For example, where did you see this? Was it newer or older-style animation? Was it gory and explicit or funny/ecchi? What did the girls look like? What did the zombies look like? What did she trip over? What ages were the girls? What were they wearing? What sort of hallway was it?

Comment: "I saw this on TikTok" isn't as much help as you might think

Answer (score -3):

Pretty sure this is *Highschool of the Dead*

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You can improve your answer by including a description of the movie that shows how it matches the question.